how do i add audio padding
I'm making a custom intro for a game I play and for the intro, it wants a .webm format I have a .webm format but for some reason, the code of the game cuts the audio off 1 second early so I wanna know how I can add 1 seconds of audio padding to this code
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -c:v "libvpx-vp9" -c:a "libvorbis" "output.webm"

Do you mean 1 second more of silence?

yeah like 1 to 2 second more of silence

the thingy that adds more silence is called apad I think

and i have absolutely zero ideas on how to use it

Adding 2 seconds of silence to the audio, if you want more or less change the part in duration=2:
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -f lavfi -i "anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100:duration=2" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[audio];[audio]asetpts=N/SR/TB[audio]" -map 0:v -map [audio] -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libvorbis output.webm


Also easy to do with Audacity, which i believe acts as GUI fro ffmpeg, in this case.
